# Is this an error => Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0

Tags: apt

my box told me that I should run:

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

So I did it, after that, I run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

And these messages that I have never seen before appear:

```
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
```

Are they error messages?

Thanks in advance

Below are the command and the complete output:

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Hit:1 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial InRelease
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease 
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Hit:4 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease 
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release 
Hit:6 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB] 
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Hit:9 http://archive.neon.kde.org/user xenial InRelease 
Hit:10 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease 
Hit:12 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x xenial InRelease 
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Fetched 204 kB in 1s (175 kB/s) 
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using KDE neon 5.11 I learned a couple of things that those messages aren't errors and that with the following command everything updates the ubuntu and KDE packages

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && pkcon refresh && pkcon update
```

Comment: Did not work for me. Also not clear why using pkcon in addition to apt-get would make any difference.